# How to stop any next JavaScript events to avoid XSS

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, xss

I'd like to show a text with HTML execution (formated) in the browser so it will be easy to read BUT without any JavaScript execution. It's a large text and it's very hard to read between HTML tags. So, execute HTML but not JavaScript.

**What I did:** I loaded this text in an `<iframe>` so I can have full control and I tried to show the text like this:

```
<script>
throw new Error('This is just to abort javascript');
</script>
<?php echo $text ?>
<script>
throw new Error('This is just to abort javascript');
</script>
```

The console does show an error but even so, if I have
`$text = '<script>alert(1)</script>';` this script gets executed anyway.

Another XSS example that I'd like to avoid.
`$text = '<a href="#" onmouseover="alert(1)">this is a fake url</a>';`

Basically, abort any JavaScript execution from the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to totally remove any JS scripts in `$text`, or do you want them to be displayed as text in the iframe without executing?

Comment: You can't disable javascript execution just for a certain area of the code. Only for the whole page (and also only by hand in your browser settings). I'm afraid you wount get around filtering scripts out or escape it.

Comment: Another xss vulnerability to be aware of which may break plans of filtering out anything that's not 'href'... `<a href="javascript:alert(1);void(0);">I'm totally legit, click me.</a>`

Comment: @blcook223 - the idea is to stop executing **any** JavaScript code, not only `<script>` tags. As @samlev say, there is `href="javascript:` and also we can have events (`onmouse...`, `onload` and many others). So, "parse the text and remove scripts" is not a solution. I need to force the browser to abort/stop any scripts. I got my solution: cannot be done :) Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) to prevent any inline JavaScript from executing.

[See here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy) for browser compatibility.

It is also recommended to run any user input through an HTML sanitizer too, as this will help protect browsers without CSP support. Using BBcode or something like MarkDown is also recommended, rather than allowing users to enter raw HTML as this is much simpler (and complexity is the enemy of security).

Comment: Cool stuff! I did not know about this header. BBCode is not an option. The client must be able to copy-paste some HTML into our platform and we must read the content. Is there workaround for IE? (God, I hate Microsoft so much for this browser!)

Comment: I believe the partial support provided is enough to prevent scripting. Using this with an established HTML sanitizer would usually be adequate (please don't try and write your own, _it's complicated_!).

Comment: IE does not know about this header. I tried `header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'");` and `header("X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'");` and `header("X-Webkit-CSP: default-src 'none'");` On Firefox it's OK, IE does not react in any way.

Comment: [It should do](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy) (IE 10 +).

Comment: I know, caniuse.com also says that it should. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I have IE11 on Windows8.1. I tried `default-src 'none'` and also `default-src not.valid.website.here`. Same old story: on Firefox/Chhrome it's OK, on IE it's not.

Comment: I still cannot find nothing to make it work. I marked your answer as accepted because it is a nice solution for the future (I hope Microsoft will eventually get out of the 20th century)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this isn't really possible. The reason that that doesn't work is because the error stops *that script* from executing, but doesn't stop all scripts on the page from executing.

If you're trusting HTML input from the user, you're simply going to have XSS vulnerabilities, unless you try to parse their input and remove anything that could cause a javascript event to fire. Don't try this, you're in for a lot of heartache if you do.

Ultimately, this is why things like [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and [Textile](http://txstyle.org/) exist.

I guess the answer to "what you should do" depends on what you're expecting the user to actually send you, but ultimately you should be running any user input through [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and/or [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: I posted the question hoping that someone knows some magic :) Thank you also for MarkDown and Textile links.